# Find the volume of solid

Tags: calculus

Use any method to find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region enclosed by the curves $y$=$x^2$+8 and $y$=$x$+20 about the $x$-axis. $$\\$$
Points of intersection are: $x$= -3 and $x$= 4

Comment: Use the washer method. Draw a picture and you'll easily convince yourself of the inner and outer radius.

Comment: What book did you use to learn how to do this problem?

Comment: I tried but I couldn't find the right answer

Comment: calculus 3rd ed

Answer (score 2):

First, find the points of intersection.

Set the equations equal to each other: $x^2$+8=$x$+20, you get $x$=-3, and 4.

$$\\$$
The Washer's method is: $$ \int \pi(R^2 - r^2)  dx.$$

[image]

$$\\$$
From the graph I inserted, notice the blue line on top ($y$=$x$+20), making it the $R$. The equation $y$=$x^2$+8 is the $r$.

So you're integral will be:

$$ \int_{-3}^4 \pi((x+20)^2 - (x^2+8)^2) dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

The inner radius is $r=x^2+8$ and the outer is $R = x + 20$. After finding the points of intersection you have, $$ \int_{-3}^4 \pi(R^2 - r^2) \ dx$$

[image]

Comment: That's a tremendous hint.

Comment: @user221227: Yeah I was trying to leave the details to the OP.